# How to plot decimal values in JQPlot Bar graphs?

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I am using jqplots to generate bar graphs . I am able to generate exact graphs for whole numbers. But I am not able to generate graph for the values having decimal points. Below is the code I have used :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;  
var s1 = ['1.5','3.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '3.0', '0.0'];  
var ticks = ['New mould', 'Raw Material', 'color/size', 'Imported/Catalogue' , 'Printing' , 'plating' , 'other'];   
plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {    
// Only animate if we're not using excanvas (not in IE 7 or IE 8)..           
animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,     
seriesDefaults:{        
renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,         
pointLabels: { show: true }          
},     
axes: {        
xaxis: {     
renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,     
ticks: ticks              
},
yaxis: { tickOptions: { formatString: '%.2f' } }
},  highlighter: { show: false } 
});           
$('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataClick',function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data)
{               
$('#info1').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);          
}       
);   

}); 

</script>
```

I am getting the erroe as follows:

this[r]._ticks[0] is undefined
http://blrsrigwd11074.itcinfotech.com:81/Windchill/netmarkets/javascript/report/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js
Line 57

PLease help me out on this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could spot the error by looking at your code on the first go.
But I wasn't sure, if that was the actual cause for the error.

You are using the data array as `var s1 = ['1.5', '3.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '3.0', '0.0'];`
jqPlot is trying to read the values from the data-array, and it expects an `Integer` or `Decimal` value(s).

In your case, you are passing `String` values in the array. So all you need to do is remove the single quotes('') from the values.

The array should be something like this, `var s1 = [1.5, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0]; //Remove quotes`

To confirm this, I ran your code thru JSFiddle. Here's the link [JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/anish_nair/4yjr3zhd/)

Try both the arrays in the fiddle, values with quotes(`var s1 = ['1.5', '3.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '3.0', '0.0'];`) and without quotes(`var s1 = [1.5, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0]`). The one with single quotes won't plot the bar-chart.

Hope it helps.